# Make [azure-cache] a synonym of [azure-caching]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[azure-cache](/questions/tagged/azure-cache) should be a synonym of [azure-caching](/questions/tagged/azure-caching) -- both are related to [Windows Azure Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx). The tag wiki for the tag should be the one associated with [azure-cache](/questions/tagged/azure-cache) since is more comprehensive.

**EDIT**: please note that I've edited the request since its creation, because my original request did not take into account the terminology used by Microsoft to name the cache technology.

Comment: Starting on manual re-tag. Is anyone else with me? Let's go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you posted seemed good, so I did a manual re-tag on 55-ish questions, copied over the tag wiki, and now after 24 hours the old tag should disappear!

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest and for your work -- I appreciate that.